# pandas groupby numbers for a new column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df column "days" of 1000 row of records.

If the days less than 7.0 days (0-7) group as "1-6 days"

If the days more than 7.1 but less than 14.0 days (7.1 - 14.0) group as "7-14 days"

If the days more or equal to 15 days group as "> 14 days"

How can i create a new column "Days_Group" to represent the days grouping?

```
e.g of days values:
1 3.0
2 4.6
3 14.9
4 7.1
5 15.1
6 109
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['Days_Group'] = pd.cut(df['days'],
                          bins=[0,7,14,np.inf], 
                          labels=['1-6 days','7-14 days','> 14 days'],
                          include_lowest=True)
print (df)
    days Days_Group
1    3.0   1-6 days
2    4.6   1-6 days
3   14.9  > 14 days
4    7.1  7-14 days
5   15.1  > 14 days
6  109.0  > 14 days
```

---

```
df['Days_Group'] = pd.cut(df['days'],
                          bins=[0,7,14, pd.np.inf], 
                          labels=['1-6 days','7-14 days','> 14 days'],
                          include_lowest=True)
print (df)
    days Days_Group
1    3.0   1-6 days
2    4.6   1-6 days
3   14.9  > 14 days
4    7.1  7-14 days
5   15.1  > 14 days
6  109.0  > 14 days
```

EDIT: If timedeltas in `days`:

```
print (df)
               days
1   3 days 00:00:00
2   4 days 14:24:00
3  14 days 21:36:00
4   7 days 02:24:00
5  15 days 02:24:00
6 109 days 00:00:00

df['days'] = df['days'].dt.total_seconds() / 24 / 3600
print (df)
    days
1    3.0
2    4.6
3   14.9
4    7.1
5   15.1
6  109.0
```

Comment: use `pd.np.inf`

Comment: or add `import numpy as np`

Comment: error: bins must be of timedelta64 dtype. Could it be my date/time subtraction value not right.  df['Days'] = (df['DATECREATED'].dt.normalize() - df['DEPOTINDATE'].dt.normalize())

Comment: weird , my Days output is e.g 4 days. It should show the 4 only but no idea why 'days' in the data

Comment: Give me a sec, I add solution.

Comment: Thanks it work now, except for days = 0.0 , days_group will indicate as nan ? Should be under 1-6 days group.

Comment: Yes, then need `include_lowest=True`, I change answer.

Comment: @okl - Glad can help!

Answer (score 2):

#### `np.searchsorted`

```
labels = np.array(['1-6 days', '7-14 days', '>14 days'])
bins = np.array([7, 14])

df.assign(Day_Group=labels[bins.searchsorted(df.days)])

    days  Day_Group
1    3.0   1-6 days
2    4.6   1-6 days
3   14.9   >14 days
4    7.1  7-14 days
5   15.1   >14 days
6  109.0   >14 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut)

```
df.assign(Day_Group=pd.cut(df['Days'],
                           [0,7,14,np.inf],
                           labels=['1-6 days','7-14 days','> 14 days']))
```

Output:

```
    Days  Day_Group
1    3.0   1-6 days
2    4.6   1-6 days
3   14.9  > 14 days
4    7.1  7-14 days
5   15.1  > 14 days
6  109.0  > 14 days
```